# How to make app full screened

Tags: android, fullscreen

I know it's possible to make an app real fullscreen for Nexus Devices.
But i can't get a tutorial. You know? That the Back, Home and MenuButton are gone.

Comment: Its called Immersive mode. Search for it.

Comment: Belongs to Android.StackExchange

Answer (score 1):

```
getWindow().getDecorView()
            .setSystemUiVisibility(
                    View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY
                            | View.INVISIBLE);
```